# Can I use both the JAX-RS and RAML extensions in Restlet in the same application?

Tags: jax-rs, restlet, swagger, raml

I am preparing a ReSTful service which I would like to have documented using RAML (and perhaps Swagger as well), but it seems that I cannot implement both JAX-RS and RAML in the same application at the same time.

I have created an Application class for JAX-RS as follows:

```
public class Application extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        // Use the reflections library to scan the current package tree for
        // classes annotated with javax.ws.rs.Path and add them to the JAX-RS
        // application
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(this.getClass().getPackage().getName());
        return reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Path.class);
    }
}
```

I attach the JAX-RS Application object as follows:

```
    Component component = new Component();
    Server server = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, PORT);
    component.getServers().add(server);

    JaxRsApplication jaxRsApplication = new JaxRsApplication(component.getContext().createChildContext());
    jaxRsApplication.add(new Application());
    jaxRsApplication.setObjectFactory(objectFactory);
    component.getDefaultHost().attach("/rest", jaxRsApplication);
```

And I would also like to implement the RAML extension, but it looks like it is tied to the Restlet Router and having it's own Application class. Is there a way to combine the two?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the RAML extension of Restlet isn't designed to be used within JAXRS application. That said you can define a resource that provide the RAML content based on classes `ApplicationIntrospector` of Restlet and `RamlEmitter` of RAML parser, as described below:

```
public class RamlResource {
    private Definition definition;

    @Path("/raml")
    @GET
    public String getRaml() {
        return new RamlEmitter().dump(RamlTranslator
                         .getRaml(getDefinition()));
    }

    private synchronized Definition getDefinition() {
        if (definition == null) {
            synchronized (RamlResource.class) {
                definition = ApplicationIntrospector.getDefinition(
                               Application.getCurrent(),
                               new Reference("/"), null, false);
            }
        }

        return definition;
    }
}
```

It's the way the RAML extension of Restlet works. You could also use such an approach for Swagger but be careful since Swagger 1.2 requires several resources (a main and several sub ones with each categories). It's not the case anymore for Swagger 2.

You can notice that there is a JAX-RS support for Swagger in the extension `org.restlet.ext.swagger`.

----- Edited

Perhaps can you make a try with this class that corresponds to a port of the class `JaxRsApplicationSwaggerSpecificationRestlet` to RAML. It's based on the class `JaxRsIntrospector` which seems relevant for JAX-RS application:

```
public class JaxRsApplicationRamlSpecificationRestlet extends Restlet {
    private Application application;
    private String basePath;
    private Reference baseRef;
    private Definition definition;

    public JaxRsApplicationRamlSpecificationRestlet(Application application) {
        this(null, application);
    }

    public JaxRsApplicationRamlSpecificationRestlet(Context context, Application application) {
        super(context);
        this.application = application;
    }

    public void attach(Router router) {
        attach(router, "/api-docs");
    }

    public void attach(Router router, String path) {
        router.attach(path, this);
        router.attach(path + "/{resource}", this);
    }

    public Representation getApiDeclaration() {
        Raml raml = RamlTranslator.getRaml(
            getDefinition());
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

        try {
            return new StringRepresentation(
                      mapper.writeValueAsString(raml), 
                      MediaType.APPLICATION_YAML);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return new StringRepresentation("error");
        }
    }

    public String getBasePath() {
        return basePath;
    }

    private synchronized Definition getDefinition() {
        if (definition == null) {
            synchronized (JaxRsApplicationRamlSpecificationRestlet.class) {
                definition = JaxRsIntrospector.getDefinition(application,
                    baseRef, false);
            }
        }

        return definition;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
        super.handle(request, response);

        if (Method.GET.equals(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setEntity(getApiDeclaration());
        } else {
                response.setStatus(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        }
    }

    public void setApiInboundRoot(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    public void setApplication(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    public void setBasePath(String basePath) {
        this.basePath = basePath;
        // Process basepath and check validity
        this.baseRef = basePath != null ? new Reference(basePath) :  null;
    }
}
```

You can use this class like this:

```
JaxRsApplication application
       = new JaxRsApplication(component.getContext());
MyApplication app = new MyApplication();
application.add(app);

new JaxRsApplicationRamlSpecificationRestlet(app);

(...)
```

There is no need for a dedicated resource. Please note that this code is a bit experimental ;-) I could propose it back for a contribution for the extension raml in Restlet...

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: This looks promising, but I cannot seem to get it to work. When I tried to implement as described, I get a NullPointerException in ApplicationIntrospector.addEnpoints()... The result of baseRef.getSchemeProtocol() is null. I assume this is something I missing in my initial setup of the application?

Comment: FYI, the source code for my project can be found at : https://github.com/InfoSec812/restlet-deltaspike-demo

Comment: I made a little more progress by using a different constructor for 'Reference'. The problem is that although there is no exception thrown, the RAML generated is basically empty.

Comment: I edited my answer with a new approach similar to the one from the swagger extension. I'm more confident with it ;-) Can you make a try? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to implement what you described above but I am still getting an error on the server side. I am wondering if I am doing something different during the initialization which is causing a problem. I have pushed my changes to the GitHub repo linked above if you are interested in looking.